# How to start multiple await proccesses at the same time in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, asynchronous, async-await

Basically I have few async functions that are waiting each other to finish and I want to start mutliple proccesses of these functions at the same time. Now my code waits till 1 proccess (1 loop) will finish and then starts another and I want to start more loops at the same time.

My code:

```
async function Start() {

  console.log("Starting...")

  try {

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

             var taskid = i
    
            await AddBasket(taskid)
            const url = await Basket(taskid)
            const urlek = await Guest(taskid, url)
            await ShipInfo(taskid, urlek)
}
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.error(chalk.red("Error while starting", error));
  }
}

Start()
```

```
In practice it looks like this: 
TASK: 0 Adding to cart
TASK: 0 Successfully added to cart
TASK: 0 Posting some to get checkout page.
TASK: 0 Successfully posted
TASK: 0 Scraping for checkout link.
TASK: 0 Successfully scraped
TASK: 0 Submitting shipping info
TASK: 0 Successfully Submitted shipping info
TASK: 1 Adding to cart
TASK: 1 Successfully added to cart....
```

I want to make it looks like:

```
TASK: 0 Adding to cart
TASK: 1 Adding to cart
TASK: 2 Adding to cart....
```

Comment: you may want to use `Promise.all` with an array, and await the result of that

Comment: The point of using `await` is to make async code appear to be synchronous. If you really want it to be async, don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the body of the loop into an async function. Then you can start multiple without waiting for each.

Make an array of the promises returned by the function, and use `Promise.all()` to wait for all of them at the end.

```js
async function oneBasket(taskid) {
  await AddBasket(taskid)
  const url = await Basket(taskid)
  const urlek = await Guest(taskid, url)
  await ShipInfo(taskid, urlek)
}

async function Start() {
  console.log("Starting...")
  let baskets = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    baskets.push(oneBasket(i));
  }
  try {
    await Promise.all(baskets);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(chalk.red("Error while starting", error));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, thats what i wanted.